# How do I get the right parts for my BMX?

Tags: maintenance, identify-this-bike, bmx

Was told it was a Sunday bmx 20" just don't know the year, so how will I know how to order the proper parts?

Serial number is wtu148p048e.

Comment: Tried to fix it but it's still horribly unclear.

Comment: As it stands now, it sounds like you have a frame and you need to spec parts for it. We don't do product recommendation here. If you want to know how to spec a whole bike, that's too broad for one question; since you don't have the expertise to do this, take whatever you have for the bike to a bike shop, and ask them to help you spec it up (and likely outfit the parts on the bike).

Comment: Also, note that it may not be worth putting parts on this frame; it may not be the frame you think it is (I don't know about Sunday serial numbers, or what their frames look like though). A lot of bikes (particularly BMX) are sold under false pretenses. A picture may help someone identify if it is really a Sunday BMX or some random piece of junk.

Comment: If you have the frame at hand, get a tape measure and a vernier caliper, learn to use them, measure the exact dimensions for every part and look up the standards. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: If it's a question of getting new frame-specific BMX bits such as brake bosses, gyro tabs, etc, just call or email Sunday or take the frame to a BMX shop. That stuff isn't super universal so just cut to the chase and get it from a source that knows how to give you the right thing.

Comment: Parts are largely interchangeable between BMX bikes, once you match the basic brake scheme, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to seemingly popular belief there is no giant database of bike serial numbers, manufacturers, models and original components that people with sufficient reputation on Bicycle Stack Exchange magically have access to.

If you want to build a bike up from a frame you simply have to learn about the various standards and sizes of wheels and hubs, bottom brackets and cranks, seatpost diameters, head set bearings and steerer tube diameters, brake mountings etc etc etc.

Additionally, for any bike there is a vast selection of different components available. You will get to make a lot of choices about style, cost, weight and quality.

The Park Tool Company articles and YouTube Channel are my favorite resources. They focus on current road and mountain bikes and don't have much BMX specific content. A great deal will be applicable to BMX bikes though.